# changing the citation style in LateX

Tags: latex, biblatex

I am very new to LaTex so my question may be really naive. I am writing my PhD thesis using this [template](https://box.hu-berlin.de/f/a273b3dc02d34c578083/?dl=1). The problem is that I need to change the citation style so that it based on author year not numbers as in the template. I tried many times but it always fails with many error messages due to the macros of the template.

It will be a great help to guide me how to change the style. Unfortunately I have only limited time to finalize the thesis.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please add a [mre] directly to your question, so we don't have to follow external links.

Answer (score 1):

I reviewed the documentation of biblatex and found that the answer is very easy. One should make sure that the option style in the package biblatex is set to authoryear as `style = authoryear,`.

To enable the natbib Compatibility (to use \citep and \citet etc), you have to add `natbib=true,`.